# How to add more tabbar items based on device size in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement Tab bar menu. Initially for iphone7 or iphone 11 pro max, it should show 2 menu items. If app running ipad then it should show 4 menu items in tabbar controller.

Is it possible to achieve this? If yes can you suggest me sample of it..

For example iphone7 or iphone 11 pro max:

tabbar items are like tab1 and tab2

For ipad tabbar items like tab1, tab2, tab3 and tab4.

Any help much appreciated pls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let firstVC = FirstViewController()
firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .one, tag: 0)

let secondVC = SecondViewController()

secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .two, tag: 1)

let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
thirdVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .three, tag: 2)

let fourthVC = FourthViewController()
fourthVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .four, tag: 3)


if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    let tabBarList = [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC, fourthVC]
    viewControllers = tabBarList
} else {
    let tabBarList = [firstVC, secondVC]
    viewControllers = tabBarList
}

yourTabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
```

Comment: exactly now i have been trying this.. any how thanks for answering.. Whats viewControllers?

Comment: Ohh that's great, i've edited my answer to clarify what viewControllers is! Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: i have added firstviewcontroller class in storyboard, now i have added label and button, but it does not shows anything. if add programmatically in firstviewcontroller it works fine.

Comment: Did you apply necessary constraints ? your controller is not visible or your elements like button and label is not getting displayed ?

Comment: no i have not used constraints .. just drag uiview into viewcontrollers..thats it

Comment: So try giving background to the viewcontroller so that you can be sure that your controller is visible, and if you are using AutoLayout then you need to give constraints. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The most is 5 on an iPhone, iPhone pro or on an iPad. When you add a sixth you get the 1st four plus a More tab with the other two. This can't be changed using a standard UITabBarController. On tapping on more tab you can show multiple tabs in grid fashion.

Search github or other resources like pods.